# GLSL/OpenGL 2.1: Specular Lighting using Uniforms

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, specular

So, I've begun a quest to implement awesome lighting without using OpenGL's lighting system. I've successfully implemented Phong diffuse lighting. Specular is giving me trouble.

I need to know what spaces the OpenGL constants I'm using occupy, because it seems they are mis-transformed, and that it results in lighting glitches.

I have confirmed that there is no problem with my C++ code by successfully loading and running a Phong diffuse shader. The C++ code may, however, be passing invalid data to the shaders, which is one of the things I'm worried about. I will paste my shaders with comments, as well as all C++ code directly pertaining to the shaders (although I'm 90% sure the problem is in the shaders).

In these images, the light sources are large points, and the axes are shown.
The lights are rotating at y = 0 around an icosphere.

Here's the diffuse, so you get an idea what the model is...
[image: Note I haven't done per-pixel yet...]
Note I haven't done per-pixel yet...

Here's the Fresnel lighting, as shown in source...
[image: Note how the lit faces are facing the light, not somewhere between the light and the camera]
Note how the lit faces are facing the light, not somewhere between the light and the camera

Here's the Blinn-Phong, which I had to multiply by 30...
[image: Note again how the lit faces point towards the light source]
Note again how the lit faces point towards the light source, and also the fact that I had to multiply the Specular factor (S) by 30 to achieve this

Vertex Shader Source (loaded from "dirlight.vs")

```
const int MAXLIGHTS = 4;

uniform bool justcolor = false;

uniform int lightcount;
uniform vec4 lightposs[MAXLIGHTS];
uniform vec4 lightdirs[MAXLIGHTS];
uniform vec4 lightdifs[MAXLIGHTS];
uniform vec4 lightambs[MAXLIGHTS];

//diffuse
vec4 D;
//specular, normaldotlight
float S, NdotL[MAXLIGHTS];
//normal, eyevec, lightvecs, halfvecs
vec3 N, E, L[MAXLIGHTS], H[MAXLIGHTS];

void main() {
    //if(lightcount > MAXLIGHTS) lightcount = MAXLIGHTS;
    D = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    S = 0.0;

    N = gl_Normal;
    E = normalize(vec3(-gl_Vertex));

    for(int i = 0; i < lightcount; i++)
    {
        //calculating direction to light source
        L[i] = normalize(vec3(lightposs[i] - gl_Vertex));

        //normal dotted with direction to light source
        NdotL[i] = max(dot(N, L[i]), 0.0);

        //diffuse term, works just fine
        D += gl_Color * lightdifs[i] * NdotL[i];

        if(NdotL[i] >= 0.0)
        {
            //halfvector = normalize(lightdir + eyedir)
            H[i] = normalize(L[i] + E);

            //Blinn-Phong, only lights up faces whose normals 
            //point directly to the light source for some reason...
            //S += max(0.0, dot(H[i], N));

            //Fresnel, lights up more than Blinn-Phong 
            //but the faces still point directly to the light source, 
            //not somewhere between the lightsource and myself, like they should.
            S += pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(L[i], N), E)), 50.0);
        }
        else
        {
            H[i] = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
    }

    //currently only showing specular. To show diffuse add D.
    gl_FrontColor = justcolor ? gl_Color : vec4(S * 0.3, S * 0.3, S * 0.3, 1.0);

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Fragment Shader Source (loaded from "dirlight.fs")

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Excerpt from C++ main initialization...

```
//class program manages shaders
Program shaders = Program();
//attach a vertex shader, compiled from source in dirlight.vs
shaders.addShaderFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "dirlight.vs");
//attach a fragment shader compiled from source in dirlight.fs
shaders.addShaderFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "dirlight.fs");
//link program
shaders.link();
//use program
shaders.use();

//Program::getUniformLoc(const char* name) grabs the location
//of the uniform specified
GLint sTime = shaders.getUniformLoc("time");
GLint lightcount = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightcount");
GLint lightdir = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightdirs");
GLint lightdif = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightdifs");
GLint lightamb = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightambs");
GLint lightpos = shaders.getUniformLoc("lightposs");
GLint justcolor = shaders.getUniformLoc("justcolor");

glUniform1i(justcolor, 0);
glUniform1i(lightcount, 2);
//diffuse light colors
GLfloat lightdifs[] = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f,
                      1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
glUniform4fv(lightdif, 2, lightdifs);
glUniform4f(lightamb, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.f);
```

Excerpt from C++ main loop...

```
//My lights rotate around the origin, where I have placed an icosphere
GLfloat lightposs[] = {-4 * sinf(newTime), lighth, -4 * cosf(newTime), 0.0f,
                       -4 * sinf(newTime + M_PI), lighth, -4 * cosf(newTime + M_PI), 0.0f};
glUniform4fv(lightpos, 2, lightposs);
```

Comment: Technically you should do the lighting calculations in the fragment shader, not the vertex shader; that's one of the key purposes of fragment shaders: Implement per fragment illumination models.

Comment: I'm implementing it in the vertex shader first, so I can have everything in the same place. I'm moving to per-pixel later. I don't want room for errors in between them, not until that's the only thing I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few important things missing from your code. First you should transform vertex position and normal into eye space. Lighting calculations are easiest there. Vertex position transforms using the modelview matrix, the normals transform with the transposed inverse of the modelview. Usually light positions are in world coordinates, so it makes sense to supply an additional matrix from world to eye coordinates.

Comment: Is everything I'm handling in world space? (in the source above)

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: No. It's a mixture of model local space (gl_Vertex, gl_Normal), some undefined space you lack providing the semantics for (lightpos, lightdir), and eye space (gl_Position = ftransform()); Like I already told you: It would be far easier using the vertex shader only to bring things into a common space, eye space that is, then do the lighting calculations in the fragment shader.

Comment: To leave the local model space and go to global, would I multiply model-local variables by the inverse of gl_ModelView? How do the projection and modelview matrices relate to one another?

Comment: You multiply vertex position with modelview to get to eye space, and normals with inverse transpose of modelview. Lights usually are in world space, you must bring them to eye space as well. Just look at any tutorial explaining the transformation pipeline, either with shaders or fixed function. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/directional-light-per-pixel/

Comment: Success! Your answer had me realize what I needed to know, so I went and found information on how the matrices and spaces relate to each other. Specular lighting working just fine.